# SQL Server 2014 Extract Top Level CategoryID from Tree Structure

Tags: sql-server, tree

I have a Tree structure with some 10.000 Nodes
translated into more than 20 languages
for totally some 230.000 Records

Relevant Fields in the table are:
`LanguageID, CategoryID, ParentCategoryID, CategoryLevel, isLeaf, Expired, TopLevelCategoryID`

I need to populate `TopLevelCategoryID` with the proper value, thus `CategoryID where CategoryParentID IS NULL --(or where CategoryLevel=1)`
for all records where
`isLeaf=0 and Expired=0 and TopLevelCategoryID is NOT NULL`

After googling a lot I wrote this query

```
Declare @LanguageID nvarchar(10)='FR'

  ;WITH Explode AS
  (
    SELECT  categoryID AS major, 
            categoryID AS minor, 
            LanguageIDID, 
            CAST(CategoryID as nvarchar(max)) AS levels
    FROM dbo.Categories
    Where LanguageID=@LanguageID 
    AND CategoryLevel=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT MJ.major, MN.categoryID, MN.LanguageID, MJ.levels +','+CAST(MN.CategoryID as nvarchar(max)) levels
    FROM Explode AS MJ
    JOIN dbo.Categories AS MN ON MJ.minor = MN.ParentCategoryID 
    WHERE MN.LanguageID=@LanguageID 
    AND (','+MJ.levels+',' NOT LIKE  '%'+CAST(MN.CategoryID as nvarchar(max))+',%')
    AND MN.Expired=0
  )

  Update c set TopLevelCategoryID= e.major
  FROM Explode e
  JOIN dbo.Categories c ON c.categoryID=e.minor
  WHERE c.LanguageID=@LanguageID
  AND c.TopLevelCategoryID IS NULL
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

that works, but is extremely slow even if I added the @LanguageID Parameter

Surely it is not efficient..

I was also wondering if it was not better a recursive routine 
for categorylevel=6 to 1 
where for each level you put into TopLevelCategoryID the value of the ParentCategoryID
but I've not been able to manage the recursivity :-(

here some sample data with 1 language (sorry but can't create sqlfiddle with this data)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Categories (
    languageID nvarchar(3)  NULL,
    CategoryID int   NULL,
    ParentCategoryID int  NULL,
    CategoryLevel int  NULL,
    isLeaf bit NULL,
    Expired bit NULL,
    TopLevelCategoryID int NULL
)

INSERT INTO
Categories 
    (
        LanguageID, 
        CategoryID, 
        ParentCategoryID, 
        CategoryLevel, 
        isLeaf, 
        Expired, 
        TopLevelCategoryID
    )
VALUES 
    ('EN',10,NULL,1,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',20,NULL,1,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',30,NULL,1,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',40,NULL,1,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',107,20,2,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',112,10,2,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',145,20,2,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',167,20,2,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',182,30,2,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',194,20,2,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',199,145,3,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',214,112,3,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',345,182,3,1,0,NULL),
    ('EN',567,167,3,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',682,194,3,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',794,145,3,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',814,199,4,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',823,214,4,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',846,214,4,1,0,NULL),
    ('EN',880,199,4,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',896,567,4,1,0,NULL),
    ('EN',898,682,4,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',1104,823,5,1,0,NULL),
    ('EN',1120,880,5,1,0,NULL),
    ('EN',1450,814,5,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',1670,814,5,1,0,NULL),
    ('EN',1820,1450,6,0,0,NULL),
    ('EN',1940,1450,6,0,0,NULL)
```

Can somebody give some hints?

Thanks!

> **BREAKING NEWS**

I tried with a different approach, more suitable with my skills, thus, setting `TopLevelCategoryID` as `parentCategoryID` and move this value from low `CategoryLevel` levels to highest with this query:

```
DECLARE @cnt int=1

WHILE @cnt < 8
BEGIN
    UPDATE c SET TopLevelCategoryID = COALESCE(c2.TopLevelCategoryID,c2.ParentCategoryID)
    FROM Categories cat
    JOIN Categories c2 
         ON c.ParentCategoryID=c2.CategoryID 
         AND c.LanguageID=c2.LanguageID
    WHERE c.CategoryLevel=@cnt
    AND c.Expired=0
    AND c2.Expired=0

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```

from preliminary test seems working, but processing time pass from more than 4 hours to less than 1 second, and although it would be great I presume there's something wrong: from what I saw, all tree structure are processed with CTE and Recursion: cannot be so simple as it seems me now:

Can somebody help to find what I did not consider and made wrongly?
Thanks!

Comment: This looks like one-time job so may be you don't need to waste time on optimizing it. It won't be really fast because of this: `(','+MJ.levels+',' NOT LIKE  '%'+CAST(MN.CategoryID as nvarchar(max))+',%')` and actually you lost leading "," inside of `like`.

Comment: And I don't really understand that filter. Does `MJ.minor = MN.ParentCategoryID` give many duplicates, I mean each category may show up on different levels?

Comment: Could you please also provide sample data. Your query is a little bit fuzzy for me :) The recursive part seems to be the category table. Somehow you also join it with Explode table. I'm sure this section is slowing the performance. In fact, you are joining category to its parent_category for upper level. You can join to Explode after you run your recursive query on category table. Then maybe you can join it to Explore table.

Comment: Hi! actually it is not one-time job but a weekly job, since some categories are added and other deleted on weekly basis.  Yes, I lost the leading ',' in like while copying. `MJ.minor=MN.CategoryParentID` 'SHOULD' join the categoryID of the CTE with ParentCategoryID of the Categories Table

Comment: @Eralper Sure! just added

Comment: @Joe remove that `like`. Why is it there? Because of loops in hierarchy?

Comment: @IvanStarostin that `NOT LIKE....` 'SHOULD' helps to reduce processing time avoiding to test path that has already been resolved

Answer (score 0):

surely it is not the solution for everybody, but for my specific requirements works well although not using neither CTE neither Recursivity, only reiteration:  actually requires to know in advance the max level of reiteration. But advantage is that on more than 200.000 records takes less than 1 second compared to more than 250 Minutes (not seconds!) of the CTE+Recursion solution posted at beginning

```
DECLARE @cnt int=1

WHILE @cnt < 8
BEGIN
    UPDATE c SET TopLevelCategoryID = COALESCE(c2.TopLevelCategoryID,c2.ParentCategoryID)
    FROM Categories cat
    JOIN Categories c2 
         ON c.ParentCategoryID=c2.CategoryID 
         AND c.LanguageID=c2.LanguageID
    WHERE c.CategoryLevel=@cnt
    AND c.Expired=0
    AND c2.Expired=0

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```